# Expository texts on advanced subjects

Tags: soft-question, big-list, online-resources

I'm reading *The Princeton companion to Mathematics* and *Basic Notions of Algebra* by Shafarevich. Both of them are really pleasant reading, the first one treats the topics from a more elementary point of view and the second one use advanced examples from other areas and from algebra itself. From this I got to know the *Encyclopaedia of Mathematical Sciences* of Springer, I'm wondering if you know more texts like this, they don't have to be books, they could be papers/blogs/etc. I'm looking for well explained and motivated introductions to advanced fields/ideas in contemporary Mathematics.

Comment: I think you might find the Unapologetic Mathematician interesting and relevant: http://unapologetic.wordpress.com

Answer (score 4):

- A book that comes to mind is Abhyankar's Lectures in Algebra. It is a fascinating book.
- Miles Reid's Undergraduate Commutative Algebra should also fit your description. I am not sure about his other undergraduate book on Algebraic Geometry. I have not read this book.
- I also like notes by Dr. David R. Wilkins. He has notes on a wide variety of subjects.
- Notes by James Milne cannot be overlooked.
- I don't know if Richard Courant's "What is Mathematics?" qualifies as an introduction to advanced areas in contemporary mathemtics. I certainly learned a lot from it at some point.
- May be, Mumford's Red Book qualifies your criteria?
- A nice introduction to Algebraic Geometry is Fulton's book "Algebraic Curves".
- Ravi Vakil's notes on Foundations of Algebraic Geometry are also becoming very popular (though they are not elementary).
- I also like Cox, Little and O'Shea's "Ideals, Varieties and Algorithms".
- Rosen and Ireland's "A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory"
- The Catsters on youtube explaining Category Theory.

Comment: Also, the books and notes mentioned above are a bit biased toward Algebra and Algebraic Geometry. I am sure there are great texts for other fields, and would like to know of some.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of mathematical blogs. For example, I can mention [Qiaochu's](http://qchu.wordpress.com/) and also [shamelessly plug my own](http://williewong.wordpress.com/). I can also direct you to look at the "Other Maths Blogs" section of the links on my blog.

Just in case you weren't aware of this: [John Baez's *This Week's Finds*](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/TWF.html) is the granddaddy of mathematical blogging, and contains *a lot* of gems along what you are looking for.